# Resizing arrays without converting them to images

Tags: python, arrays

I have a few arrays of shape

```
(137,236)
```

Can I reshape them into `(128,128)` just like we would do with an image? I do not want to convert the array to an image, then resize and then retrieve the array

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide more detail? These are arrays of numbers, or some other data type like colors? How do you want to handle fuzziness (weighted averages vs dropping elements proportionally)? Do you want to maintain aspect ratio, squish vs crop, etc.? What research have you done in existing methods for doing this, and what problems have you run into from that research?

Comment: The values in these arrays are pixel values for 137 x 236 images. I want to feed a 128 x 128 array into a neural network. But for that I need to reshape my current array